# can python make variables itself?

Tags: python, variables

Can python make variables itself ?
I have to do some program that needs too many variables.
So like can it do it is self ?
Example :

```
`x= 10

#and here i need to make for example x1 but i dont want to type it

x1 = 10
```

`

Comment: I don't know what your use case is, but the code to do something like you want to write would be longer than just writing `x1 = 10`.

Comment: You should look into Python dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi there are a lot of options but like chepner says every would be larger than writing variable names.

if you have only numeric you can use a list:

```
x = [10,11,12,13,14]
```

then your variables will be `x[0] x[1] x[2] ...`

If you want to identify every variable with a name you can use a dict. supose that you want to create 10 variables with names `x1,x2,... x10`

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(10):
    my_dict[f'x{i}'] = 10
```

then accessing via `my_dict['x1'] , my_dict['x2']`